# GitHub Pagesでcssとhtmlをアップしても、cssが反映されて表示されない

Tags: html, css, github-pages

プログラミング初心者です。
GitHub Pages上でhtmlファイルとcssファイルを公開したのですが、以下のリンクをみる限りどうもcssが反映されません。
https://shogonino.github.io/myblog/

デバックするために、以下のことをやってみました。

・CSSの階層指定の変更
・`<base href="{{site.github.url}}">` をhead内に記載
・キャッシュのクリア

html上のcssをリンクさせるための記法はあっていると思うのですが、どなたかお力を貸していただけますでしょうか。ソースコードは整っていないですが、こちらです。
https://github.com/shogonino/myblog

お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: style.cssの中身が 「html」ですよ。まずはCSSとして正しいものに差し替えてください。

Comment: GitHub 上で直接ファイルを編集しているので無ければ、まずローカルでファイルを開いて意図した通りに表示されるかを確認してみるべきかとも思います。

Comment: >style.cssの中身が 「html」ですよ。本当ですね。書き換えたら直りました!!!

Comment: 解決してよかったです。まさか、回答になってしまうとは思いませんでした。回答しておいたので承認のチェックをお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style.cssの中身が 「html」なので、中身をCSSのものに修正してください。